# Unable to find nested array in JSONObject (org.json)

Tags: java, arrays, json, selenium

I am trying to geta nested JSON array from within a JSON file but I keep getting an error that the array I am specifying cannot be found.

My JSON file:

```
{
"invested": [
    {
        "email" : "test@test.com",
        "password" : "test"
    }
],
"notInvested": [
    {
        "email" : "test@test.com",
        "password" : "test"
    }
]}
```

Here is how I get the JSONObject from file:

```
public JSONObject returnJSONObject(String path) throws JSONException, IOException 
{
    path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + path;
    
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(parseJSONFile(path));

    return obj;
}

public static JSONObject parseJSONFile(String filename) throws JSONException, IOException 
{
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));
    Reporter.log(content);
    return new JSONObject(content);
}
```

And here is where it fails. When I try to call 'validLogins.get("invested")';

```
JSONObject validLogins = returnJSONObject("valid-user-logins.json");
JSONArray loginArray = (JSONArray) validLogins.get("invested");
```

I have checked that the JSONObject I am returning contains the JSON as string and it does, I just cant figure out why it cant find the nested array 'invested'? I get this error when i run the program:

```
loginPageTest
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["invested"] not found.
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I copy your code and in my case works fine, return "[{"password":"test","email":"test@test.com"}]". The only thing that I change is the path "/valid-user-logins.json". Could you check to change the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `JSONObject` constructor on your JSON string, and then calling this same constructor on the result:

```java
public JSONObject returnJSONObject(String path) throws JSONException, IOException 
{
    path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + path;
    
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(parseJSONFile(path)); // JSONObject constructor called here

    return obj;
}

public static JSONObject parseJSONFile(String filename) throws JSONException, IOException 
{
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));
    Reporter.log(content);
    return new JSONObject(content); // JSONObject constructor called here
}
```

In short,  you're basically doing this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new JSONObject(content));
```

To fix this, in `returnJSONObject()`, replace the line

```java
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(parseJSONFile(path));
```

with

```java
    JSONObject obj = parseJSONFile(path);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call the constructor when you call the method **parseJSONFile**

Replace this

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(parseJSONFile(path));
```

with

```
JSONObject obj = parseJSONFile(path);
```

**Class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException {
        JSONObject validLogins = returnJSONObject("/valid-user-logins.json");
        JSONArray loginArray = (JSONArray) validLogins.get("invested");

        System.out.println(loginArray);
    }

    public static JSONObject returnJSONObject(String path) throws JSONException, IOException {
        path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + path;

        return parseJSONFile(path); //this is the line with problems
    }

    public static JSONObject parseJSONFile(String filename) throws JSONException, IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));
        return new JSONObject(content);
    }

}
```